# How to calculate declination of the Sun if its right ascension is known?

Tags: the-sun

How to calculate declination of the Sun if its right ascension is known?
I am BSc (NS) student.

Comment: For basic homework questions it would be far better to show your current thinking/working. Otherwise you will not learn...

Answer (score 2):

As discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Overview), the path of the Sun *resembles* a sine wave (see the image below), with a (semi-)amplitude equal to the [axial tilt of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Earth), usually denoted $\varepsilon$, about 23.4 degrees. A simple formula, which might be accurate for your purposes, is the following: if $a$ denotes the right ascension (in hours), the declination $\delta$ is given by the following formula:

$$\delta = \varepsilon \sin(2\pi\frac{a}{24h})$$

The actual formula is more complicated. From the [formulas linked to by @barrycarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Equatorial_coordinates):

$$\alpha = \arctan(\cos\varepsilon \tan\lambda)$$

$$\delta = \arcsin(\sin\varepsilon \sin\lambda)$$

we obtain

$$\tan\alpha = \cos\varepsilon \tan\lambda$$

$$\frac{\tan\alpha}{\cos\varepsilon} = \tan\lambda$$

so

$$\lambda = \arctan\frac{\tan\alpha}{\cos\varepsilon}$$

Plugging this into the declination formula, and using the fact that $\sin(\arctan(x)) = \frac{x}{\pm\sqrt{x^2+1}}$, we get

$$\delta = \arcsin(\sin\varepsilon \frac{\tan\alpha}{\pm\sqrt{\tan^2\alpha+\cos^2\varepsilon}})$$

(here the right ascension $\alpha$ is measured in radians or degrees, not hours).

[image]

<sub>(picture taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic#/media/File:Constellations_ecliptic_equirectangular_plot.svg), originally by Cmglee, Timwi)</sub>

Comment: If this is true, it suggests that elevation would be `c*sin(azimuth)` where azimuth is measured in radians, since it's the same situation where you're measuring one great circle in terms of another. It seems reasonable that this should be true, but I'm not sure it actually is. I'll dig further.

Comment: @barrycarter it is, the [conversion between ecliptic and equatorial coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system#Conversion_between_celestial_coordinate_systems) should look familiar.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_of_the_Sun#Equatorial_coordinates gives the sun's ra and dec in terms of ecliptic longitude, and dec does not appear to be `c*sin(ra)` or anything similar, even after applying trig substitutions. Again, I could be wrong-- it's just that I vaguely remember being bitten by this before.

Comment: you're right. Trigonometry is hard :(

Comment: Tell me about it! I'm trying to do a question/answer with some basic astronomy formulas and it's ugly: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/ASTRO/bc-astro-formulas.m